# multiple count statements in 1 sql query without subselect

Tags: sql, join, count, group-by, multiple-tables

Is it possible to do this query **WITHOUT using a subselect**?

#### tables

- user:
- id
- name

#### value_type_1

- id
- user_id
- value

#### value_type_2

- id
- user_id
- value

I would like a sql query that would return:

```
id | name | Count(value_type_1) | Count(value_type_2)
1    foo     5                     2
2    bar     3                     7
n    etc..   x                     y
```

Comment: Why are you seeking to eliminate the sub select? Performance concerns? Tool limitations? Something else?

Comment: Because I use a lot of tables and conditions and the subselect too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You can use a join

```
select user.id, user.name, count(distinct value_type_1.id),count(distinct value_type_2.id)
from user
   left join value_type_1 on user.id = value_type_1.user_id
   left join value_type_2 on user.id = value_type_2.user_id
group by user.id, user.name
```

Comment: This answer is correct, with the reasonable assumption that "id" is unique on each table.  The comment on the below solution is wrong.  Although the query might generate a cross product, the distinct undoes that.

Comment: I have used a join, but missed the distinct.
Thank you, that was a big help!